# Wordpress if in term*

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

i am having trouble with conditional and custom post types.

i would like to set something up like this:

```
<?php 
if (in_term('products')){
include ('products.php'); 
}elseif (in_term('downloads')){
include ('downloads.php'); 
}else {
    //Nothing Happens
}?>
```

Obviously this doesnt work, but if there is an alternative anybody knows then please share :)

Thank you,

Dan

Comment: Not quite sure what you are looking for....? Your title asks about taxonomy, and your code idea hints at it, but you ask about a CPT? What are you trying to conditionalize for, and on? Maybe an edit just to clarify what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term

So...

```
<?php 
if ( has_term('products', 'your_custom_taxonomy', $post ) ) 
{
    get_template_part('products'); 
}
elseif ( has_term( 'downloads', 'your_custom_taxonomy', $post ) )
{
    get_template_part('downloads'); 
}
?>
```

Change `your_custom_taxonomy` to whatever that taxonomy name is. I changed include to [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part).  If this is found in a theme file, that's the correct function to use.  If it's in a plugin, feel free to change it back.

Comment: thank you for the response. i would like to know if its possible to pull in array of terms by the term parent? rather than manually typeing all terms. hope this makes sense?

Comment: You're still going to have to check if the post has the term by typing it out if that's what you want.  But you can get all the terms with either `get_the_terms` or `the_terms`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms & http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms